# Expected value of product of dependent variables.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, martingales

I've just made a quick search but can't seem to find a satisfying explanation for the following:

> Let $X_i,...,X_n$ be $\{-1,1\}$-variables that are not necessarily independent, and $E[X_i]=0$. Then: $$E[e^{\sum_i X_i}]= \prod_i E[e^{X_i}|\{ X_j: j < i \}]$$.

Can I have a derivation and/or the intuitive idea behind this?

=======
**Edit:** This is in the context of a discussion of martingales. Please see the screenshot below. Also if my question could be rephrased better, please help me do so.

[image]

Comment: I feel like this must be related to the [chain rule for random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)#Chain_rule_for_random_variables). Indeed setting $Y_i = e^{X_i}$ should simplify the issue.

Comment: If the  random variables are not independent why you did not determine the why they are dependent or related?Why you did not explain about the structure of dependency?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but what does $E[ e^{X_i} \mid \{X_j : j < i\}]$ mean?  E.g. for $i = n = 2$, this would be $E[e^{X_2} \mid X_1]$ right?  But technically that is a function of $X_1$ and therefore a random variable, not a pure number...  More generally, where do you find this claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive this using the Law of Total Expectation, which states that $E[X] = E[E[X \mid Y]]$. With that, just note that:
$$
E[e^{X_1+...+X_n}] = E[E[e^{X_1+...+X_n}\mid X_1,...,X_{n-1}]]= $$
$$= E[e^{X_1+...+X_{n-1}}E[e^{X_n} \mid X_1,...,X_{n-1}]]=$$

$$
= E [E[e^{X_1+...+X_{n-1}}\mid X_1,...,X_{n-2}]\cdot E[e^{X_n} \mid X_1,...,X_{n-1}]]=
$$

$$= E [e^{X_1+...+X_{n-2}} E[e^{X_{n-1}}\mid \{X_j: j<n-1\}]\cdot E[e^{X_n} \mid \{X_j: j < n \}]] = $$
$$
=...=\prod_iE[e^{X_i}\mid \{X_j : j<i\}]
$$

Which proves the identity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm lost right at the second equality, i.e. $E[E[e^{X_1+...+X_n}\mid X_1,...,X_{n-1}]]= E[e^{X_1+...+X_{n-1}}E[e^{X_n} \mid X_1,...,X_{n-1}]]=$. Could you elaborate? Also in the first equality, can we just condition $E[e^{X_1 + ... + X_n}]$ on any set of conditions?

Comment: To your first question, I will use only $X_1$ and $X_2$ for simplicity. Note that 
$$E[e^{X_1,X_2}\mid X_2] = E[e^{X_1} e^{X_2}\mid X_2]$$
Since the expectation is conditioned on $X_2$, we can treat $e^{X_2}$ as a constant, say $\alpha = e^{X_2}$. Therefore, as you know, in the expectation, we can factor out scalar variables, hence
$$E[\alpha e^{X_1} \mid X_2] = \alpha E[e^{X_1} \mid X_2] = $$
$$e^{X_2} E[e^{X_1} \mid X_2] $$
Finally,
$$
E[E[e^{X_1,X_2}\mid X_2]] = E[e^{X_2} E[e^{X_1} \mid X_2] ]
$$
Second question, the answer is pretty much yes. Look for Law of Total Expectation

Comment: Just to make things clearer where I left in the previous comment, note that
$$
E[e^{X_2} E[e^{X_1}\mid X_2] ] = E[e^{X_2}] \cdot E[e^{X_1}\mid X_2]
$$
Because, $E[e^{X_1}\mid X_2] $ is a constant value and can be taken out of the expectation.